# How can I format a list to print?

Tags: python, list, printing, format

How can I format a python list to print?

Example I have:

```
list = ['Name1 ', Price1, Piece1, 'Name2 ', Price2, Piece2, 'Name3', Price3,
        Piece3]
```

and I wish to format the list so it prints like this:

```
Name1
Price1 - Piece1
Name2
Price2 - Piece2
Name3
Price3 - Piece3
```

Comment: `Price1` and `Price2` are objects or what?

Comment: Price1, Price2, Price3, Piece1, Piece2, Piece3 are numbers

Comment: Is this python 3.x or 2.x?

Comment: This is Python 2.x

Comment: It seems like your application requires logical groupings of (name, price, piece), so perhaps it makes sense to maintain a list of tuples instead? You could iterate over that list and print each tuple according to your required format pretty easily as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another ugly solution:

```py
print("\n".join([lst[i] + "\n" + lst[i+1] + " - " + lst[i+2] for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you ment that `Price1` and `Price2` are strings (you forgot the `'` sign)

One solution:

```
lst = ['Name1 ', 'Price1', 'Piece1', 'Name2 ', 'Price2', 'Piece2', 'Name3', 'Price3', 'Piece3']

for i in xrange(0, len(lst), 3):
    print(lst[i] + "\n" + lst[i+1] + " - " + lst[i+2])
```

Returns:

```
Name1 
Price1 - Piece1
Name2 
Price2 - Piece2
Name3
Price3 - Piece3
```

Also never name your variable `list` list is an already used keyword in python

Comment: This solution is missing the dashes between Pricex & PieceX

Comment: just use xrange nor range

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
    name, price, piece = seq[i:i+3]
```

Then do what you want with the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(*['{}\n{} - {}'.format(*lst[i:i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list0 = ['Name1 ', 1, 2, 'Name2 ', 1, 2, 'Name3', 2, 1]
print '\n'.join(['{}\n{}-{}'.format(x,y,z) for (x,y,z) in zip(list0[::3],list0[1::3],list0[2::3])])
```

outputs

```
Name1 
1-2
Name2 
1-2
Name3
2-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = ['Name1 ', 'Price1', 'Piece1', 'Name2 ', 'Price2', 'Piece2', 'Name3', 'Price3', 'Piece3']

for i in range(0, len(ls), 3):
    print(*( ls[i:i + 3]))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is this

```
#Declare some variables for example
Price1 , Price2 , Price3 = 12 , 57 , 33
Piece1 , Piece2 , Piece3 = 5 , 4 , 2

#Create a two-dimensional array for more clear code
li = [['Name1', Price1 , Piece1] , ['Name2 ', Price2, Piece2] , ['Name3', Price3, Piece3]]

#Itterate through the array and print 
for i in range(len(li)) :
    print "\n"
    for y in range(len(li[i])) :
        if y == 0 :
            print li[i][0] 
        else:
            print li[i][1] , " , " , li[i][2]
```

It can be more improved of course and efficient. I hope I helped you, if you have any questions feel free to ask.